# What is the limit function of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(e^{-n^2}-e^{-(n+x)^2}\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{-n^2}-e^{-(n+x)^2}\right).$$

According to some theorems in my research, I found that it is convergent on $\mathbb{R}$, but I cannot find the limit function of this exactly. Anyone can help me to obtain this? thanks a lot.

Comment: What is a "limit function?"

Comment: I mean the function that the series converges to it.

Comment: The series is a function of $x$.  The partial sums of the series converge to that function.  Are you seeking a closed form solution?

Comment: yes I am, that's it

Comment: have you looked up Jacobi theta functions ?

Comment: Jacobi theta would be relevant if the sum where from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: yes I saw it on wolfram alpha page, but I had not sufficient knowledge about this, and I could not reach to any useful thing

Comment: I have collected my comments in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete solution but a collection of interesting partial results.

Let the sum in question be

$$f(x) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\exp \left(-n^2\right)-\exp \left(-(n+x)^2\right)\right)\tag{1}$$

1) Symmetry:

Define

$$g(x) = f\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\tag{2}$$

then $g(x)$ is antisymmtric:

$$g(-x) = - g(x)\tag{3}$$.

Hence follows

$$f(-x) = - 1 - f(x-1)\tag{4}$$

2) Asymptotic values

$$a = f(x\to +\infty) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \exp \left(-n^2\right) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\vartheta _3\left(0,\frac{1}{e}\right)-1\right) \simeq 0.386319\tag{5}$$

where $\vartheta _3$ is a Jacobi theta function.

And, using (4),

$$f(x\to -\infty) = -1 - a \simeq -1.386319$$

3) Integer values of $x$

lead to finite sums due to cancellations

$$f(0) = 0$$
$$f(1) = \exp \left(-1^2\right)+\exp  \left(-2^2\right) +\exp  \left(-3^2\right)+ ...\\ - \exp \left(-(1+1)^2\right)-\exp  \left(-(1+2)^2\right) - ... = \exp \left(-1^2\right)$$
$$f(2) = \exp \left(-1^2\right)+\exp  \left(-2^2\right) +\exp  \left(-3^2\right) +...\\ - \exp \left(-(2+1)^2\right)-\exp  \left(-(2+2)^2\right) - ... = \exp \left(-1^2\right)+\exp  \left(-2^2\right)$$
$$...$$ 
and generally,

$$f(k) = \sum_{n=1}^k \exp \left(-n^2\right), k = 1, 2, ...\tag{6a}$$

and by (4)

$$f(-k)= -1-f(k-1)= -1 -\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \exp \left(-n^2\right), k = 1, 2, ...\tag{6b}$$

Comment: Replacing the sum starting at $n=1$ by an integral starting at $n=0$ we obtain  $f_q(x)=\frac{1}{2}( \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)-1)$, which looks qualitatively similar to $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Dr. Wolfgang Hintze's answer. While the first part of the series has a mentioned closed form in terms of theta function, we can find an integral form for the second part, but only for $$x>0$$

Represent the series as:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-(n+x)^2}=e^{-x^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2} e^{-2nx}$$

We use the following integral representation:

$$e^{-n^2}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2/4} e^{int} dt$$

We obtain:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-(n+x)^2}= \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2/4} dt \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-(2x-it)n}$$

Using the geometric series formula, and getting rid of the imaginary part, we have finally:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-(n+x)^2}= \frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/4}  \frac{e^{2x} \cos t-1}{e^{4x}-2e^{2x} \cos t+1 } dt$$

For $x<0$ the series inside the integral diverges, and for $x=0$ the integral after summation diverges, which is why we needed $x>0$.

However, $f(0)$ is trivial and for $f(-x)$ we can use Dr. Wolfgang Hintze's result.

Comment: @ Yuriy S The integral is convergent also for x<0. The integrand has no singularities for t>0, and close to $t=0$ it is $\frac{1}{e^{2 x}-1}-\frac{t^2 \left(3 e^{4 x}+1\right)}{4 \left(e^{2 x}-1\right)^3}+O(t^4)$. Hence the integral is divergent only for $x=0$.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze, the integral converges, but the series it was originally obtained from diverges. As I said. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-(2x-it)n}$$ this geometric series doesn't converge for $x<0$

Comment: @Yuriy S would you tell me the answer of latest series if we have ‎‎‎$‎\frac{-{(n+x)}^2}{2}‎‎$ ‎‎‎instead ‎of ‎‎$‎-{(n+x)}^2‎$‎. thanks a lot

Comment: @soodehMehboodi, use the same method, only $\cos t$ changes to $\cos (t/ \sqrt{2})$ and the same happens to $x$

Comment: @Yuriy S Is $\frac{e^{-‎\frac{x^2}{2}‎}}{\sqrt[•]{\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/4}  \frac{e^{‎\sqrt[•]{2}‎x} \cos t-1}{e^{2\sqrt[•]{2}x}-2e^{\sqrt[•]{2}x} \cos t+1 } dt‎‎‎$ wrong answer

Comment: @Yuriy S I mean that $x$ is changed or $t$

Comment: @soodehMehboodi, both. As I said. $t$ only changes inside of cosine

Comment: @Yuriy S, hi again. would you introduce some books or references contain the definition of $\vartheta$ functions and example. thank you

Comment: @soodehMehboodi, try online sources first, search for links there if you really want a textbook https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html

Comment: @Yuriy S, Thanks for your advice.